# create a php page view for modules in drupal6

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I am working in drupal6 and new to drupal. I have created a custom my Account module in drupal website. In drupal the way to design integration is somthing difficult, becuase thay are showing the view what is they return from the callback function. But my question is can i create a custom php page and show that page as my module view page? Is this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to implement `hook_menu` e.g. so:

```
function YOURMODULE_menu()
{
  $items = array(); 
  // this would create a Menuitem in Adminmenu, but you can specify an other url for different locations
  $items["admin/settings/YOURMODULE"] = array(
    "title"                => "Translateable Menu Name",
    "access arguments"     => array("access administration pages"),
    "page callback"        => "drupal_get_form", // function, that will be called for this menuitem
    "page arguments"       => array("YOURMODULE_menu_admin"), // Argument givven to the page_callback function
    "type"                 => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );
  return $items;
}
```

See [hook_menu | Drupal 6 | Drupal API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_menu/6) for mor details.
In this first example your function will be called from `drupal_get_form` and you could create some forms in it like this:

```
function YOURMODULE_menu_admin()
{
  // YOURMODULE_element_name is the name of the form element
  $form['YOURMODULE_element_name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Title of the textfield'),
    '#default_value' => variable_get('YOURMODULE_element_name', ""),
    '#size' => 2,
    '#maxlength' => 2,
    '#description' => t("Description of your formfield."),
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
  return system_settings_form($form); 
}
```

Ant if you like to create a full custom page, with you own content, you can specify your own callback function in hook_menu

```
function YOURMODULE_menu()
{
  $items = array(); 
  // this would create a Menuitem in Adminmenu, but you can specify an other url for different locations
  $items["YOUR_CUSTOM_PATH"] = array(
    "title"                => "Translateable Menu Name",
    "access arguments"     => array("access custom module"), // you can define your own permission here
    "page callback"        => "your_custom_page", // function, that will be called for this menuitem
    "type"                 => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );
  $items["YOUR_CUSTOM_PATH_FOR_IMAGE"] = array(
    "title"                => "An image output page",
    "access arguments"     => array("access custom module"), // you can define your own permission here
    "page callback"        => "your_custom_image", // function, that will be called for this menuitem
    "type"                 => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );
  return $items;
}
```

Then you can implement this function freely even to output binary data an define own headers.

```
function your_custom_page()
{
  echo "this is my custom page";
}


function your_custom_image()
{
  drupal_set_header("Content-Type: image/png");

  $im = @imagecreate(110, 20);
  $background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
  $text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
  imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  "A Simple Text String", $text_color);
  imagepng($im);
  imagedestroy($im);

  // Exit here, because we don`t want the drupal footer in out Image output
  if(function_exists("drupal_exit")) drupal_exit();
  else
  {
    // Allow modules to react to the end of the page request before redirecting.
    // We do not want this while running update.php.
    if (!defined('MAINTENANCE_MODE') || MAINTENANCE_MODE != 'update') {
      module_invoke_all('exit', $url);
    }
    exit;
  }
}
```